# Microsoft Word Security Warning for Signed VBA Project

Tags: certificate, code-signing

I am attempting to setup signed VBA Projects so that I can find the right balance between security and useability.

Currently my end users are instructed to just hit "Enable Content" on Microsoft Office to allow running of the Macro's.

[image]

Obviously this is a security issue as it's a blind approval, they should in fact be told to never hit "Enable Content" and the goal is that Word will automatically run the documents because the VBA Projects are digitally signed.

I have made a cert using "SelfCert.exe". Imported it into the "Trusted Root". It shows as trused. I opened VB Edited and applied this to my document, changed Word Trust Security Center settings to "Disable all except digitally Signed". But, I still get the warning and can't figure it out. Is this a glitch? Am I doing something wrong?  Looking for help from somebody with experience with this issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have no idea why this was moved, both question and answer involve no code and this is a strictly security based question.... But I had no say in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I hadn't added the key under "Trusted Publishers". I still have some gripes about how hard that was to do/figure out and also I wish there was a Macro setting of "Disable all Macros WITHOUT notification except digitally signed ones", but thats another thread.

[image]